# What is the correct naming convention for fields in WinRT

Tags: c#, c++, oop, windows-runtime

As a **.Net** developer using **C#** for years I've been a little "confused" by some **naming conventions** used in **WinRT** for **fields**.

In **C++** the rule was simple: `"do whatever you want!"`

In **C#** on the **.Net** platform AFAIK the rules were a little more contrived:

- for `protected` fields: `camelCase`
- for `private` fields: C++ rule => `"do whatever you want!"`

And generally I've observed 2 behaviors:

- senior developers used to MFC, Win32, COM... used `_camelCase` and sometimes `m_camelCase`, probably the first being directly derived from the second
- younger developers and a lot of recent resources (tutorials, videos, books...) were consistent with naming rules of protected fields: `camelCase`

But for `WinRT` I've observed in many resources yet a new convention for private fields: `_CamelCase`

For me the naming conventions are more specific to the language than to the underlying platform, so writing my C# code differently depending on the target platform (**.Net** or **WinRT**) seems a bit odd.

So is there some official or community guidelines for this or should I apply the good old rule `"do whatever you want!"`?

Comment: This is for C#. Private: `_camelCase`; local: `camelCase`; protected: `CamelCase`. Private is sometimes `camelCase` as well but an underscore is more common.

Comment: @BenVoigt Don't be shocked, there is even a licence named this way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL ;)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Not that simple unfortunately: recently the dominating one was `camelCase` with some fun side effects when using INPC with not type-safe infrastructure and easy typos.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fixed it, but surprised you consider it too rude for SO where I think the audience is only adults and many geeks :( I'd be curious to know if anybody else was annoyed... Anyway sorry for that if this was inappropriate.

Comment: @Pragmateek: Thanks for helping to keep this site safe for work.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah ok I see for firewalls that may filter on keywords. OK I admit this is a good reason. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek this is my POV but unless there is an _official_ guideline (and you decide to follow that) then you're really free to do what you want (just be consistent across your project(s) and organization). There isn't a _trend_ or a _popular one_. Private fields are implementation details. You _may_ adhere to _something_ (if you want so) but AFAIK there isn't a _standard_ for that (at least for WinRT naming conventions). Pick one you prefer and live happy. Do you know why? IMO because you'll write 10 pro and 10 cons for each style but no one cares because they won't see that.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti As you say there is no better convention, as an example coming from Java and C++ some years ago I considered the CamelCase for naming methods an aberration and it took me some time to adopt it, but after that at least my code was similar to any other C# code so easier to understand. For me this is the best (maybe only) benefit of a naming convention. So it's why I hope there is one I can stick to without having to think too much about it.

Comment: @Pragmateek then go on with what you have. For what I saw (for WinRT but in C# because it can be decompiled) you still have the same "mess" (with or without underscore, camelCase or _camelCase or _TitleCase; the only one I didn't see - so far - is m_camelCase but I bet it'll be common for C++ code)...

Answer (score 3):

The question makes little sense.  WinRT is an api that's used by *many* languages.  At its core, it is heavily COM based and only supports interfaces.  What you see of it in a programming language is heavily filtered by the *language projection*.  For managed code it the projection is provided by the .NET runtime.  For Javascript the project is provided by the Chakra engine.  For C++ it is either WRL or the C++/CX language extension.

Most important thing the language projection does is providing features that are not actually supported by WinRT.  Like exceptions, generics, method overloads and inheritance.  Thus making it a *lot* easier to use, writing COM code was never very popular.

Naming conventions are camel-case, like they were for the winapi, minus the system Hungarian.  Javascript is notable, the language projection makes the effort to *rename* identifiers with the first letter in lower-case.  As demanded by the programmers of that language.

But the names of fields are immaterial.  Interfaces don't support fields, only properties.  Only the actual class that implements the interface can use fields.  Which is a pure implementation detail, as it is in COM, the class itself is never observable from the outside.  Re-inforced in .NET for example by the requirement that a public class must be *sealed*.

So you just pick whatever naming convention is common in the language in which you write the class.  Or, more importantly, whatever your team mates have agreed upon as the group standard.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I agree that for the public API this is not important but for source code this is primordial, particularly in the context of open source projects where the "group" is not your colleagues but the whole developers community. So the community should agree on a common rule, chosen by itself or decided by Microsoft.

Comment: I fail to see why programmers that write in C++ need to follow the same rules as programmers that write in C#.  That's going to be war, it is *illegal* in C++ to follow the preferences that Resharper forces on you.  Or why this suddenly needs to be different because of WinRT, open source projects have mixed languages before.  You are just not making a lot of sense.

Comment: I've not said that rules should be the same for all the languages. Just that it should be consistent in a given language. I know that some languages like C++ have lived a good life for decades without any conventions, but from the beginning C# came with its own, so I see no reason to change it now, hence my question (not of the greatest importance I agree).